# Setting a C3 subchart extent for a category x axis with JSON data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, metrics, c3.js

I'm using C3 to create a bar chart. I am using JSON formatted data, with a category axis.

I have a subchart i am using to implement scrolling and i would like to set a default extent with `axis.x.extent`.

Regardless of what i put in the extent array, C3 ignores it and displays the entire thing.

Code looks like this:

```
  var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: this.$element[0],
    data: {
      json: [{name: 'name-01', count: 3}, {name: 'name-02', count: 9}, {name: 'name-03', count: 7}],
      keys: { value: ['count'], x: 'name' },
      type: 'bar',
    }
    axis: {
      x: {
        type: 'category',
        extent: ['name-01', 'name-02']
      }
    }
  },
  subchart: {
    show: true
  }
});
```

Because the x values are category names, it seems i cant just use indexes. According to other stackoverflow posts.

According to other stackoverflow posts it seems like i am supposed to directly put in the category names. But that isnt working either. C3 still ignores it.

I have also tried using `min` and `max` instead of `extent`, which works, however it also sets it for the subchart, which makes it useless.

Theres very little to no documentation.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using chart.zoom

```
chart.zoom([0,1]);
```

can you can reset it using "unzoom"

```
chart.unzoom();
```